# Discord.JS property 'send' does not exist on type 'AnyChannel'

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message when a Discord bot is ready and more generally without waiting for a message or an interaction.

I tried 2 ways to do so:

```js
client.guilds.cache
    .find((guild) => guild.id === "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.id === "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .send("Some content");
```

```js
client.channels.cache
    .find((channel) => channel.id === "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .send("Some content");
```

Both work well and the message is sent to the specified channel, but because I'm using typesrcript I get an error that says:

```
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'AnyChannel'.
  Property 'send' does not exist on type 'CategoryChannel'.
```

After taking a look at the documentation, it seems that there is no method called "send" in AnyChannel or CategoryChannel types.

So my question is the following:

- Why is there a "send" method if it is not described in typescript? Is it an oversight?
- Is there an other way to send a message in a channel when the bot is ready without the need to add `// @ts-ignore`

--

Edit: Figured out that this question is a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992134/how-to-send-message-to-specified-channel-discord-js-v13-typescript) that answers the question